# Adding a hyperlink to a Google Maps info. window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, hyperlink

I'm creating a Google Map with multiple markers. Each marker shows an info. window when clicked upon. I need to figure out how to add a hyperlink to the info. window through the Javascript.

Here is an example of the Javascript that determines what text will be displayed inside the info. window:

```
"infoWindows": [{
            "id": 4980,
            "marker_id": "latitude and longitude here",
            "title": "title here",
            "subtitle": "subtitle here",
            "phone": "phone here",
            "address": "address here",
            "email": "email here",
            "web": "web here",
            "content": "content here",
            "open": 0
        }
```

Here is the Javascript that allows this information to be displayed when clicking on a marker:

```
b.settings.infoWindows[j].title.length > 0 && (l += '<div class="uber-google-maps-info-window-field uber-google-maps-title">' + b.settings.infoWindows[j].title + "</div>"), 

b.settings.infoWindows[j].subtitle.length > 0 && (l += '<div class="uber-google-maps-info-window-field uber-google-maps-subtitle">' + b.settings.infoWindows[j].subtitle + "</div>"),  

b.settings.infoWindows[j].phone.length > 0 && (l += '<div class="uber-google-maps-info-window-field">' + b.settings.infoWindows[j].phone + "</div>"),  

b.settings.infoWindows[j].email.length > 0 && (l += '<div class="uber-google-maps-info-window-field">' + b.settings.infoWindows[j].email + "</div>"), 

b.settings.infoWindows[j].address.length > 0 && (l += '<div class="uber-google-maps-info-window-field">' + b.settings.infoWindows[j].address + "</div>"), 

b.settings.infoWindows[j].web.length > 0 && (l += '<div class="uber-google-maps-info-window-field uber-google-maps-web">' + b.settings.infoWindows[j].web + "</div>"), 

b.settings.infoWindows[j].content.length > 0 && (l += b.settings.infoWindows[j].content), l += "</div>";
```

How would I add a hyperlink to this info. bubble? I am unsure how hyperlinks are formatted in Javascript. Preferably I would like to add the hyperlink to the "web" portion of the info. window. Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking to add the email as the hyperlink...

```
'<div class="uber-google-maps-info-window-field"><a href="mailto:' + b.settings.infoWindows[j].email + '">' + b.settings.infoWindows[j].email + '</a></div>'
```

or for some other hyperlink

```
'<div class="uber-google-maps-info-window-field"><a href="' + b.settings.infoWindows[j].someHyperlink + '">' + b.settings.infoWindows[j].someHyperlink + '</a></div>'
```